# Iterator declared as private member of a class is not working properly

Tags: c++

I have a program that Scan a file and save everything in a vector of tokens (a class that I created to store each token). After that it parsers all tokens and see if the are on the correct format (correct grammar). I go throw each token using iterator. However, for some reason, my class Parser does not like the way I am declaring the iterator. This is my main function:

```
 int main(){
    DatalogProgram DLP;
    bool passed = true;
        ifstream in;
        Scanner scanner;
        in.open("File7.txt");
//      in.open(argv[1]);
        Parser parse(scanner.getTokens(), &DLP);
        scanner.scan(in);
        try {
            parse.checkDatalog();
        }
        catch (Token* token) {
            cout << "Failure!\n  ";
            cout << "(" << token->getType(token->type) << ",\"" << token->value << "\"," << token->lineNumber << ")";
            passed = false;
        }
        if (passed)
        {
            cout << "Success!\n";
            DLP.printScheme();
            DLP.printFact();
            DLP.printRule();
            DLP.printQuery();
        }
        system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my Parser header file where I declare my iterator:

```
#pragma once

#include "DatalogProgram.h"
#include "Predicate.h"
#include "Rule.h"
#include "Token.h"
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Parser : public Token {

public:
    Parser() { it = tokens.begin(); }
    Parser(vector<Token*> tokens, DatalogProgram *DLP) { this->tokens = tokens; this->DLP = DLP; it = tokens.begin(); }
    ~Parser() { }

    bool checkDatalog();
    void checkScheme();
    void checkSchemeList();
    void checkIdList(Predicate* scheme);
    void checkFact();
    void checkFactList();
    void checkQuery();
    void checkQueryList();
    void checkStringList(Predicate* pred);
    void checkRule();
    void checkRuleList();
    void checkHeadPredicate(Rule* rule);
    Predicate* checkPredicate();
    void checkPredicateList(Rule* rule);
    string checkParameter();
    void checkParameterList(Predicate* pred);
    string checkExpression();
    string checkOperator();

    bool match(TokenType second, Token *token);
    void domainPrinter();
private:
    vector<Token*> tokens;
    DatalogProgram *DLP;
    vector<Token*>::iterator it;
    set<string> domain;
    stringstream expression;


};
```

DatalogProgram.h:

```
`#pragma once

#include "Scanner.h"
#include "Rule.h"
#include "Predicate.h"
#include "Parser.h"

//using namespace std;
class DatalogProgram : public Token {

public:
    DatalogProgram() {  }
    ~DatalogProgram() { }
    inline void addScheme(Predicate scheme) { schemes.push_back(scheme); }
    inline void addRule(Rule rule) { rules.push_back(rule); }
    inline void addFact(Predicate fact) { facts.push_back(fact); }
    inline void addQuery(Predicate query) { queries.push_back(query); }

    void printScheme();
    void printFact();
    void printRule();
    void printQuery();
    void printPredicate(vector <Predicate> printing);

    vector<Predicate> schemes;
    vector<Rule> rules;
    vector<Predicate> facts;
    vector<Predicate> queries;
};
`
```

And this is my error: [image]
Before I try to compile, visual studio does not say there is any error on my parser.h:
[image]

Comment: The shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. You need to edit your question, and include a [mcve].

Comment: Can you also post the code for `DatalogProgram.h`?

Comment: Yeah, I just added DatalogProgram.h to it.

Comment: Ohh I include "#include "Parser.h"" on it

Comment: And include it on main. Thank you very much @NoOrdinaryLove

Answer (score 1):

The shown header files are completely broken.

The `main` translation unit most likely includes the `DatalogProgram.h` header.

`DatalogProgram.h` immediately includes `Parser.h`:

```
#pragma once

/* ... */

#include "Parser.h"
```

And `Parser.h` then proceeds to include `Datalog.h` again:

```
#pragma once

#include "DatalogProgram.h"
```

However since `DatalogProgram.h` has already been included, `#pragma once` completely ignores this. Compilation then proceeds until:

```
Parser(vector<Token*> tokens, DatalogProgram *DLP)
```

But since `DatalogProgram` has not been defined yet, this class has not been defined. This results in your compilation error.

You need to figure out what your inter-header file dependencies should be, and fix the circular dependency; most likely by using forward declarations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursive header dependency. That won't work in C++. Forward declare `DatalogProgram` inside Parser.h and remove Parser.h's dependency on DatalogProgram.h

```
#include "DatalogProgram.h" <-- Delete this line.
struct DatalogProgram;

class Parser : public Token {
    ....
```